# Connecting to Azure from PowerShell with certificates

Tags: powershell, azure, x509certificate

I might be getting this completely wrong. I have researched on Google AND Bing regarding this but I haven't found a solution.

How can I connect to someone else's azure subscription from the PowerShell if the other person has uploaded my `.cer` file to his Azure account in order to allow me access without knowing his Azure login credentials?

What are some other ways of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the certificate to the [Set-AzureSubscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn495189.aspx) cmdlet:

```
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Certificate $certificate
```

Comment: How do I get the certificate?

Comment: Didn't you mention that `the other person has uploaded my .cer file to his Azure account`? What this tells me is that you created the certificate, exported that to a .cer file and gave that certificate to this other person. You can use the same .cer file.

Comment: I meant how do I get the certificate into the `$certificate` variable? But I got it now.
For anybody who gets stuck--> to get the certificate run:

`$certificate = Get-Item Cert:\Path\To\Certificate\Thumbprint`